# V-sync in windowed Java applications

Tags: java, awt, vsync

I've been hacking on Notch's Ludum Dare 22 entry, [Minicraft](http://www.ludumdare.com/compo/ludum-dare-22/?action=preview&uid=398). It's a 2D action-adventure game written in Java. Although the game runs at 150-200 FPS on my laptop, there's very obvious screen tearing. I'd like to fix that.

I have years of programming experience, and *some* game programming experience, but I'm completely new to Java. From what I've read, V-sync in (windowed) Java apps has been a problem in the past. Is it possible today? Are there practical workarounds?

So far, I've tried [java.awt.Toolkit.sync()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#sync()), but it didn't seem to help. I've also determined that Minicraft is already triple-buffered.

Before I spend too much more time on this, I'd like to know whether I'm heading down a blind alley. I'm happy to provide more technical information if needed.

Edit: For what it's worth, I'm on a Mac. I just tried to capture a screen recording of the tearing effect, but apparently while QuickTime is recording, the game is V-sync'd! What sense does that make? Is this an OS problem rather than a Java one?

Comment: call repaint() or paintImmediately() from a Timer class object for the JPanel paintComponent() function on ActionListener class object, as every component in Swing should be double buffered, hence also v-synched, by default.